# C# Winapp., add empty space after last row in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

We are creating a C# Winapp. with a few datagridviews.

If the grids contain just a few rows, empty space is shown below the last row (default datagridview behaviour).

If the grids contain a lot of rows, a scrollbar is shown and no empty space is shown below the last row (instead we can only scroll down until the last row is shown at the bottom of the grid).

Is it somehow possible to add empty space after the last row? (so we can scroll grids with lots of rows and thereby move the last row up from the bottom of the grid)

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean how to always show the last row?

Comment: No, I mean to make the last row scroll up with some blank space showing below.

Comment: Not sure I fully understood. Do you mean that if you have many rows and scroll bar is displayed then you want the last row to be shown on top (with blank row after it)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to define the height (or maybe min height and max height). 
So if you don't have enough rows to fill the height, you'll get a white space on the bottom, and if you have more that the height (or max height), you'll get the scroll bar with no white space.

Comment: I would like to keep some white space even if I have more than enough rows to fill the height. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: In that case, maybe try to create and insert some empty ones?

Comment: That would be the easiest solution, but adding empty rows will seriously affect a lot of our current code. So we would prefer to avoid adding extra, empty rows.